# How can I get a specific cell from detail table in ag-grid(Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid-angular

I'm working on a web application with ag-grid. What i want to achieve is, when I click on any cell in detail table(child table), an event should be fired with cell data. If you consider the below mentioned example, I want to get the 579 upon clicking it. I have gone through the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/master-detail/) but couldn't find anything helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<ag-grid-angular
  [id]="prefixId + id"
  [class]="wrapperClass"
  **(rowClicked)="onRowClicked ($event)"**
  (gridReady)="onGridReady ($event)"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered ($event)"
></ag-grid-angular>
```

check rowClicked Event.